# Why Provider.of<> doesn't work without `listen: false`?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-state

I've simple widget tree, and try to figure out why Provider.of<>() doesn't work in the GestureDetector, onTap() callback.

This is my model:

```
class ShareObject {
  int intField;

  ShareObject(this.intField);
}

class ShareObjectProvider extends ShareObject with ChangeNotifier {
  ShareObjectProvider(super.intField);

  void increment() {
    intField++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Here is my simple tree, where I try to invoke method from model:

```
class ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ShareObjectProvider(0),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: const WidgetThree(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetThree extends StatelessWidget {
  const WidgetThree({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.deepOrange,
          child: Center(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () =>
                    {Provider.of<ShareObjectProvider>(context).increment()},
                child: Text(
                  "Test ${Provider.of<ShareObjectProvider>(context).intField}",
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                ),
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Why when I change to `Provider.of<ShareObjectProvider>(context, listen: false).increment()` it start working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation,

```dart
Provider.of<T>(context)
```

works like a watch, which makes the widget to rebuild again

> listen: false

makes it work like read

in your case:

```dart
late ShareObjectProvider provider;


void initState() {
  super.initState();

  provider = Provider.of<ShareObjectProvider>(listen: false);
}
```

then use it in your `GestureDetector`

here's the [link](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#reading-a-value) for provider's documentation where the above said things are mentioned

Comment: Thank you for link to documentation. Now I figured out what was wrong. The `onTap` callback is outside the widget tree. `It's worth noting that context.read<T>() won't make a widget rebuild when the value changes and it cannot be called inside StatelessWidget.build/State.build. On the other hand, it can be freely called outside of these methods.`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not good for provider. you need to add listen : true OR listen: false.

```
Provider.of<ShareObjectProvider>(context, listen: false).increment()
```

Comment: With listen: false I get runtime exception `"Tried to listen to a value exposed with provider, from outside of the widget tree. This is likely caused by an event handler (like a button's onPressed) that called\nProvider.of without passing `listen: false`.\n\nTo fix, write:\nProvider.of<ShareObjectProvider>(context, listen: false); It is unsupported because may pointlessly rebuild the widget associated to the event handler, when the widget tree doesn't care about the value.The context used was: WidgetThree(dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<ShareObjectProvider?>])"` And the question is why?